# Ember.Select view not updating after changing the content array

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I tried to update handlebars template using EmberJS but I'm wondering how to do it

This is a code snippet from my JavaScript file.

```
App.selectedCoreController = Ember.Object.create({
content: null
});
App.FieldsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
fields: [],
active: function() {
    if (App.selectedCoreController.content) {
        console.log(App.selectedCoreController.content)
        var fields =[];
        Ember.RSVP.Promise.cast(Ember.$.getJSON('/ALL/' + App.selectedCoreController.content))
            .then(undefined, function() {
                return null;
            })
            .then(function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                return response.fields.map(function(d){
                    return d.name;
                });
            });
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}.property("App.selectedCoreController.content").cacheable()});
App.fieldsController = App.FieldsController.create();
```

This is part of the Handlebars script

```
{{view App.Select contentBinding   =App.arrays.cores
                        selectionBinding = "App.selectedCoreController.content"}}
{{view App.Select contentBinding   = "App.fieldsController.active"}}
```

After the active function is fired the content of Ember.Select regarding App.fieldsController.active is never changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After deep searching I figured out the solution.

The Problem was that the returned array is inside Ember.RSVP.Promise
that's why Ember.Select does not detect the changes in the array.
The correct Implementation of action function is as follows:

```
active: function() {
    if (App.selectedCoreController.content) {
        Ember.RSVP.Promise.cast(Ember.$.getJSON('/ALL/' + App.selectedCoreController.content))
            .then(undefined, function() {
                return null;
            })
            .then(function(response) {
                App.FieldsController.fields = response.fields.map(function(d) {
                    return d.name;
                });
            });
        console.log(App.FieldsController.fields);
        return App.FieldsController.fields;        
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}.property("App.selectedCoreController.content").cacheable()
```

And this is a detailed [solution](http://www.badrit.com/blog/2014/7/28/ember-select-not-changing-its-view-after-changing-the-content-binding-array)